# Android: Migration of database when data is moved from one table to another

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

We are using the [Room library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) in our Android app. In my current version of the app with DB version 1, I have a table Table1 which has a fields id, thumbnailUrl. Now we are making some changes and thus have a new table in DB version2 which has one more table Table2 with fields id, data: ByteArray where data represents the actual data that was stored in thumbnailUrl.

So when there is a migration from DB1 to DB2, I need to create Table2 which is straightforward. But how do I populate table 2. For this, I need to get each row of table1, fetch the URL, and save to table 2. The Room migration method `fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase)` does not have enough context to perform all this. So how should this be handled

Comment: What specific context do you think is missing?  The provided [SupportSQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase) allows you to do all the basic SQL operations, such as queries in Table1 and inserts into Table2.

Comment: I can do only database operations there. I need to fetch the data from the server as instaed of url I store the actual bytes in Table2

Comment: You will have to get the server context needed for url fetch from singletons or other static resources you create.

Comment: You should also consider using the migration operation to add the field to `Table1` (e.g. `ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN data BLOB`, but leave it null.  Then fetch the url and update the table after the database is opened and before the data is needed.

Comment: I am considering just creating table2 and later populating it out of migration process.